# Locate the paper "Extensions of general algebras" by Eilenberg

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, paper-request

I'm looking for the paper

> *Extensions of general algebras*, S. Eilenberg, Ann. Soc. Polon. Math. 21, (1948). 125–134 ([MR0026647](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=26647) in Mathscinet)

It is supposedly hosted at the Digital Repository of Scientific Institutes (RCIN) [here](http://rcin.org.pl/dlibra/docmetadata?id=24030), but I cannot access it, although I have registered in the site.

Can someone locate another online copy, or send one to me?

Comment: the RCIN site says that this article is protected by copyright, so I'm afraid you won't be able to find an online copy, at least not a legal one...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Wow, I have needed ANOTHER reading of the message to acknowledge that "library" in this case probably means "physical library" and not "digital library". Since they give you the very same message when you are not registered, I thought that they were merely warning you that you needed to register in order to be able to read it...

Comment: indeed, the copyright rules in Europe are quite restrictive: until 70 years after the death of the author the publication may only be accessed electronically when you are sitting behind a computer that is physically located in the library; these are obviously rules from before the internet era...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally been able to look at the paper via a university library.